# Need explanation on why my pi is equal to 0

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I was rewriting the code below using OpenMP task to parallilize the Pi program.

Original Code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static long num_steps = 1024*1024*1024;
#define MIN_BLK  1024*1024*256

double pi_comp(int Nstart,int Nfinish,double step)
{  int i,iblk;
double x, sum = 0.0,sum1, sum2;
if (Nfinish-Nstart < MIN_BLK){
  for (i=Nstart;i< Nfinish; i++){
     x = (i+0.5)*step;
     sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x); 
  }
}
else{
  iblk = Nfinish-Nstart;
  sum1 = pi_comp(Nstart,         Nfinish-iblk/2,step);
  sum2 = pi_comp(Nfinish-iblk/2, Nfinish,       step);
  sum = sum1 + sum2;
}return sum;
}
int main ()
{
int i;
double step, pi, sum;
double init_time, final_time;
step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

init_time = omp_get_wtime();
sum = pi_comp(0,num_steps,step);
pi = step * sum;
final_time = omp_get_wtime() - init_time;
printf(" for %ld steps pi = %f in %f secs\n",num_steps,pi,final_time);

}
```

OpenMP Code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static long num_steps = 1024*1024*1024;
#define MIN_BLK  1024*1024*256

double pi_comp(int Nstart,int Nfinish,double step)
{  int i,iblk;
double x, sum = 0.0,sum1, sum2;
if (Nfinish-Nstart < MIN_BLK){
  for (i=Nstart;i< Nfinish; i++){
     x = (i+0.5)*step;
     sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x); 
  }
}
else{
  iblk = Nfinish-Nstart;
  #pragma omp task firstprivate(sum1)
  sum1 = pi_comp(Nstart,Nfinish-iblk/2,step);
  #pragma omp task firstprivate(sum2)
  sum2 = pi_comp(Nfinish-iblk/2, Nfinish,step);
  sum = sum1 + sum2;
}return sum;
}
int main ()
{
int i;
double step, pi, sum;
double init_time, final_time;
step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

init_time = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single
sum = pi_comp(0,num_steps,step);
}

pi = step * sum;
final_time = omp_get_wtime() - init_time;
printf(" for %ld steps pi = %f in %f secs\n",num_steps,pi,final_time);

}
```

I dont know why the output for the OpenMP program has pi = 0 instead of pi itself when testing the speed of a certain amount of thread. Is there something I did wrong in the OpenMP code that didn't give me pi?

Output:

```
g++ -fopenmp  -c pi_recur_omp.cpp
g++ -fopenmp  -o pi_recur_omp pi_recur_omp.o -lm
./pi_recur 
 for 1073741824 steps pi = 3.141593 in 4.562793 secs
./pi_recur_omp 
 for 1073741824 steps pi = 0.000000 in 2.990318 secs
```

Comment: Note that the type of `1024*1024*1024` is `int`. Storing that value as a `long` promotes that `int` value, but the calculation is still done as `int` and could overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd say the mistake is using recursion at all. It doesn't really gain you much (if anything at all). I'd probably just do a simple iterative version:

```cpp
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static long num_steps = 1024*1024*1024;

double pi_comp(int Nstart,int Nfinish,double step)
{  
    int i,iblk;
    double sum = 0.0,sum1, sum2;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i=Nstart;i< Nfinish; i++){
        double x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x); 
    }
    return sum;
}
int main ()
{
    int i;
    double step, pi, sum;
    double init_time, final_time;
    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

    init_time = omp_get_wtime();
    sum = pi_comp(0,num_steps,step);
    pi = step * sum;
    final_time = omp_get_wtime() - init_time;
    printf(" for %ld steps pi = %f in %f secs\n",num_steps,pi,final_time);

}
```

Result:

```
for 1073741824 steps pi = 3.141593 in 0.455449 secs
```

Comment: You have a race on x....

Comment: @JimCownie: Oops.

Answer (score 1):

Your OpenMP code is not working properly because of:

1. `sum1` and `sum2` should be shared. Using the `firstprivate` clause (which is the default) makes them private, so the updated values are not available outside the tasks.
2. You have to wait for tasks to finish before you can sum them, so a `#pragma omp taskwait` line is needed.

So, your code can be corrected using:

```
#pragma omp task shared(sum1)
sum1 = pi_comp(Nstart,Nfinish-iblk/2,step);
#pragma omp task shared(sum2)
sum2 = pi_comp(Nfinish-iblk/2, Nfinish,step);
#pragma omp taskwait
sum = sum1 + sum2;
```

As pointed out by @JerryCoffin a simple iterative method gives much better performance compared to your recursive code using tasks.

Comment: Although this does fix the problem of producing the wrong answer, at least in my testing, it's around 40% slower than the version I posted (presumably due to contention over the shared variables, though I haven't tried to verify that). The exact ratio probably depends on the number of cores though--more cores increases contention, so this will probably scale almost linearly up to (say) 4 cores, but probably lose quite a bit worse with (say) 32 or 64 cores.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I agree with you regarding the performance, but the OP's question was about why the code is not giving the correct pi value. It may be a homework to calculate pi using divide and conquer method. I have added a comment to my answer, thank you.